# Firebase react native-Could not get a document field from firestore to display in react native app

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am new to react native and firestore

Context:
Firestore has a document "Users" and "Location" is a field.

Requirement : I want the location of one user/logged in user to display in the react native app.
I have written the following code, however post login the Location field is empty.
Please suggest where am I wrong.

[image: Firestore]

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, Button, TextInput, ScrollView, Stylesheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import *  as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      profileuser: [],
      profileuserlocation:''
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
       firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get().then(snapshot => {
          let profileuserlocation = snapshot.data().Location;
                this.setState({ profileuserlocation: snapshot.data().Location });
        });
      }

  render() {
        const profileuserlocation=this.state.profileuserlocation;

  return (
    <View>
         <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}> {this.state.profileuserlocation}</Text>
    </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a bit late but just in case you never found the answer...

The standard way to get the current user's uid is:

```
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          firebaseUser = {
             uid: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName,//this and the email can also be got from firebaseUser 
            email: user.email
          };
          this.setState({ uid: firebaseUser.uid });
        }
      });
```

Then, if you just want to display the field from your doc you don't need to use snapshot - that's really for if you want to keep watching for changes in the field and is used in a different way.  If you just want to retrieve the field one time then use:

```
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(this.state.uid)

this.docRef
    .doc(this.state.uid)
    .get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {

//useful ES6 'destructuring' technique for if there are many fields you are 
//saving
            const {
                Location
            } = doc.data();

            this.setState({
                Location
            })

//or for one field you can use "this.setState({Location:doc.data().Location})"

          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

You can get some good examples in the documents: [firestore docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this today and revert .

Comment: You are very welcome...If the answer works for you please feel free to 'accept' it by ticking on the grey tick next to my answer!  Thank you!